# Building tenant specific docker images using Jenkins & Deployment in kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

**My Application Structure**

I am developing a tenant based application in service oriented architecture with deployment using kubernetes and Jenkins. In my application , It contains 15-20 number of microservices developing using spring boot. The each microservice need to be deploy separately for different customers. If I have 5 customer, I need to deploy 15 microservice for these 5 customer.This is the description about my tenancy model.

**Deployment Planning**

For this application I am planning to use kubernetes and Jenkins for deployment and implementing CI/CD pipeline.

**My Findings**

The nature of my application is building the images for different customer from same code by using spring cloud config server active profile functionality. Means In my docker file , I am launching the particular image by defining which is the active profile. Like the following,

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=<Profile_Name> dbdata-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here I am configuring profile in config server. So here I am using same code for creating multiple images which belongs to each customer.

**Confusion**

If I am following this style, how I can create and launch different images from same code repository using Jenkins?  Is possible to launch multiple images using Jenkins from same code repository?

In summary, how can I understand multiple image creating and deployment as per above application structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have several microservices, it's better to use tools like [Helm](http://helm.sh) + [Chartmuseum](https://github.com/kubernetes-helm/chartmuseum) to simplify management of these services. In this case you will have individual release (and Kubernetes namespace) per tenant. You can use different docker images tags if different docker images per tenant is required.

As for Jenkins part, I don't see any problems (you can build any number of docker images from 1 repo):

- create job to produce & upload docker image(s)
- create job to produce & upload Helm chart(s)
- create job(s) to deploy/update releases in Kubernetes

It's not required to build different docker images if they differ only in command line. This command line (or env variable) can be overridden in a Kubernetes resource description.

Comment: Thank you sir. I understood your points. Actually I need to build multiple images from one repo in suh a way that. Need to launch application by specifying active profile. I am using one spring cloud config server with different profile/configuration. And need to launch application by specifying active profile. Like this I need to create multiple images. So each time the  "-Dspring.profiles.active=<Profilename>" parameter is changing acording to profile name. Here each config server profile/configuration representing each client. So each client image need to deploy in separate nodes.

Comment: I hope that you understood my confusion. I need to launch spring boot application and build image according to the active profile from spring cloud config server. So confused about building of images / automating script of Jenkins to manage this scenario.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your problem completely. Jenkins can run any shell script. In this script array with possible configurations is required (specific to your setup). Then you can build app and docker images in the bash loop with required changes to source code and Dockerfile. Simpliest template language to use it in Dockerfile for bash is `envsubst`.

Comment: Can you please refer my Issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149046/building-multiple-docker-images-from-same-spring-boot-code-by-using-spring-confi